# Terraform compare keys two different maps and copy value

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have module which outputs map, `module.platformusers.paths`, like this:

```
{
    "user1_test" = "user1_value_path"
    "user2_test" = "user2_value_path"
    "user3_test" = "user3_value_path"
}
```

I have to iterate over `local.musyers` map and take the key and compares with  `module.platformusers.paths` key, and if the key contains in the second map, then I have to copy the value

```
{
    "user1" = "Allen"
    "user2" = "john"
    "user3" = "Rose"
}
```

I want to have something like this when I am assuming if the are individual

```
resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "userspath" {
  name  = "Allen"
  type  = "String"
  value = "user1_value_path"
}

resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "userspath" {
  name  = "john"
  type  = "String"
  value = "user2_value_path"
}

resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "userspath" {
  name  = "Rose"
  type  = "String"
  value = "user3_value_path"
}
```

I am trying as shown here, but it is not working as my keys are not an exact match:

```
resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "userspath" {
  for_each =  module.platformusers.paths
  name  = ${each.value}
  type  = "String"
  value = lookup( module.platformusers.paths,  ${each.key}, "")
}
```

How to apply contains here ?

Answer (score 0):

There might be better ways to do this, but here is one quick way i could think of..
If the difference in keys going to be just "_test" as you have shown above, it might be simple actually. You can use format function to add "_test" up and do a lookup.

In you sample code, you were not looping against local.musyers..
Note: its case sensitive. You can use UPPER function to make it insensitive.

```
resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "userspath" {
  for_each =  local.musyers
  name  = ${each.value}
  type  = "String"
  value = lookup(module.platformusers.paths, format("%s_test", each.key) , "missing")
}
```